# How to execute *.sql file with python in SSMS

Tags: python, json, sql-server-2017

GOOD MORNING

I just have a question please 
is there apossibility to execute a .sql file with python in Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio ?
If there is a possibility , please help ..

Comment: SSMS is a tool. You *don't* need it to execute SQL commands from a language. Use `pyodbc` as [shown here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-2017) to connect and execute queries. What do you *actually* want to do and why the JSON tag?

Comment: I downloaded a json file by using this code :
import wget

print('Beginning file download with wget module')

url = 'https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=8d934220cd86473fbd2213119180103&q=dalya'  
wget.download(url, 'current.json')
And now I am trying to execute a .Sql file that containt a request to add the contents of the json file to my table 
So how to do it ?

Comment: My assumption is that the .sql file is a script which takes your JSON and inserts it into a table? If that is so, that file is most likely meant to be run from SSMS manually.

Comment: Sorry, hit enter too soon. So, as @PanagiotisKanavos says above, why not use `pyodbc`. E.g. you open the `json` file in python, parses out the data you want to insert into the table and use the various `pyodbc` commands to insert the data.

Comment: Thank you everyone I find a solution 
you need to ctreate a *.bat file that contain this :
sqlcmd -S serverName -E -i pathToyour SqlFile..sql
then execute it by using python :
import subprocess
subp = subprocess.Popen("C:\\pathToYourBatchFile.bat", shell=True)
subp.communicate()

and voila !

Comment: @RIKI you don't need Python at all then. You don't even need that batch file, just run the `sqlcmd` command